# Clean-up redundant <None Remove="..."/> from .csproj file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, csproj

I copied a file in dotnet core project, in project explorer, was unable to change its name, so excluded the file from project, renamed in file system, and added again to project with different name. Now, in the `.csproj` file, there is the following redundant row.

`<None Remove="File - Copy of FileX.js"/>`

I would like to remove it, and I know I can go and manually edit the `.csproj` file, but it seems to me that there should be a better, cleaner, more user friendly way to get rid of those redundant rows. I couldn't find one though.

Can anyone tell me of standard method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might end up with a powershell script which works on the xml nodes:

```
param($path)
$MsbNS = @{msb = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'}

function RemoveElement([xml]$Project, [string]$XPath, [switch]$SingleNode)
{
  $nodes = @(Select-Xml $XPath $Project -Namespace $MsbNS | Foreach {$_.Node})
  if (!$nodes) { Write-Verbose "RemoveElement: XPath $XPath not found" }
  if ($singleNode -and ($nodes.Count -gt 1)) { 
    throw "XPath $XPath found multiple nodes" 
  }
  foreach ($node in $nodes)
    $parentNode = $node.ParentNode
    [void]$parentNode.RemoveChild($node)
  }
}

$proj = [xml](Get-Content $path)
RemoveElement $proj '//msb:None Remove' -SingleNode
$proj.Save($path)
```

untested, but should work.